# Pick only one record from a JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, datatable

I'm trying to extract a record from a JSON array but it doesn't seem to work.
Here my code :

```
 DataTable table = ConvertJsonToDatatable(responseBody);
 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(table.Columns[1].ToString(), "transformation");
```

The MessageBox isn't showing. I have checked responseBody and the variable isn't empty at all.
Here the structure of this variable (and the JSON array rear)

```
{
"data": 
    [
        [
          1651217520000,
          1.0562,
          1.0562,
          1.056,
          1.0561,
          0,
          0
        ],
        [
          1651217580000,
          1.0561,
          1.0563,
          1.0561,
          1.0561,
          0,
          0
        ]
    ],
          
"events": null
}

public static DataTable ConvertJsonToDatatable(string jsonString)
        {
            var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            // Find the first array using Linq
            var linqArray = jsonLinq.Descendants().Where(x => x is JArray).First();
            var jsonArray = new JArray();
            foreach (JObject row in linqArray.Children<JObject>())
            {
                var createRow = new JObject();
                foreach (JProperty column in row.Properties())
                {
                    // Only include JValue types
                    if (column.Value is JValue)
                    {
                        createRow.Add(column.Name, column.Value);
                    }
                }
                jsonArray.Add(createRow);
            }
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonArray.ToString());
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to extract/pick one value from this array (which is a string in my code) ?

Have a nice week end everyone and thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the implementation of ```ConvertJsonToDatatable```.

Comment: I can see an array in  an  array. Can you post json you want pls?

Comment: what is inside ConvertJsonToDatatable() function? are you reading data array separately?

Comment: @adv12 Sure, my mistake I'm sorry I forget it, I edited the original post, thanks

Comment: @Serge hmm I want to read these kind of values : 1.0562, or even the timestamp inside the "data" part of the JSON

Comment: @PowerMouse I tried to read it separately with this function (added by edit in the original post, sorry for the forgetting) but it's not returning the values like the timestamp of 1,0562 from a specific row

Comment: Why not just use normal JSON deserialization and then map the result to a datatable? way simpler, more readable, and not meaningfully less performant.

Comment: @NickBailey yes but how to map the result of the deserialization to a data table ? you could have the best way but due to my bad level it's not easy, is it possible to show me a good documentation/base code to do that

Comment: you are trying to convert array of arrays in to datatable. there are no columns/field names
1. json need to be adjusted to define array elements, 2 make list of arrays and populate DataTable rows.

Comment: @PowerMouse So I could not just convert JSON into data table and just pick the row I want ? I tought it could be down with a simple loop

Comment: The fastest approach to convert to class, and do foreach on list of items to populate datarows, or use as list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i probably would be marked negative, but i try to explain how it looks like inside. i made example to show tow to get back list of arrays it might visualize for you.

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"data\":[[1651217520000,1.0562,1.0562,1.056,1.0561,0,0],[1651217580000,1.0561,1.0563,1.0561,1.0561,0,0]],\"events\":null}";
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    foreach (JToken token in obj.FindTokens("data"))
    {
        foreach (JArray row in JArray.Parse(token.ToString()))
        {
            row.Dump();
            row[0].Dump("first element");
            
        } 
    }
    
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static List<JToken> FindTokens(this JToken containerToken, string name)
    {
        List<JToken> matches = new List<JToken>();
        FindTokens(containerToken, name, matches);
        return matches;
    }

    private static void FindTokens(JToken containerToken, string name, List<JToken> matches)
    {
        if (containerToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            foreach (JProperty child in containerToken.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                if (child.Name == name)
                {
                    matches.Add(child.Value);
                }
                FindTokens(child.Value, name, matches);
            }
        }
        else if (containerToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JToken child in containerToken.Children())
            {
                FindTokens(child, name, matches);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result would be an array of jarray
[image]

so you can build you DataTable rows

Comment: You will never be marked negative by me ! You and the others help me a lot to understand all my mistakes, I will try your code but first of all thanks for your time, I will catch your code and try to show only by example the first element from a row in a MessageBox (so with a string)

Comment: Ok the row.Dump wasn't recognized but System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString(), "h"); works very well. I have to thank you for all your help and time, you closed hours of work ! have a nice week end

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix table creating code

```
public static DataTable ConvertJsonToDatatable(string jsonString)
{
    var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    // Find the first array using Linq
    var linqArray = jsonLinq.Descendants().Where(x => x is JArray).First();

     //or maybe this would be enough
    var  linqArray = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["data"];

    var jsonArray = new JArray();
    foreach (var row in (JArray)linqArray)
    {
        var createdRow = new JObject();
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in row)
        {
            i++;
            createdRow.Add("col" + i.ToString(), (string)item);
        }
        jsonArray.Add(createdRow);
    }
    return jsonArray.ToObject<DataTable>();
}
```

how to use

```
DataTable table = ConvertJsonToDatatable(responseBody);
string val = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("col2");
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(val, "transformation");
```

Comment: I'm sorry to take all your time, but it seems to not be working at all by passing from double to string, no Messagebox even not any "col2"

Comment: @CK I am always testing my code. It is working properly. You have to replace double  in 2  places -  in a method and in main code

Comment: obviously I make a lot of mistakes and that's why we loose time, but actually it seems there is not any other double in my code, I double-checked

Comment: @CK Just copy paste my method again, it is easier

Comment: I copy past every time ! the other reply help me to find my way, but I have to thank you for all your dedicated time, you closed hours of work, have a nice week-end !

Answer (score 0):

.Dump() is a left over from linqpad. Good tool. Same as console.write

Comment: Ok I understand better. Very thanks for all your help and have a nice end of week ! By the way, any idea to have the token before the last token (JArray test = JArray.Parse(token.Last.ToString()); )           I'm trying to get not .Last but just one step before

Comment: row[row.ToArray().Length-2]