# How to change a key value pair within a nested json structure C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Hello everyone and thanks for helping me in advance.
The following question might sound silly but I'm a beginner about it.

I have the following json which comes from a web api:

```json
{
    "status": "OK",
    "cases": {
        "_id": "61f8126266221531009f8909",
        "procedureLower": "AT&T PLANT V.1",
        "nameLower": "AT&T PLANT V.1 - v.1 - 31.01.2022",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-01T15:06:32.483Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-31T16:46:26.139Z",
        "device": "56a0b485303163de1a64e894",
        "procedure": {
            "_id": "61e918809033533000bc1034",
            
        "version": {
            "_id": "61f8106266221531009f8908",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-31T16:37:54.193Z",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-31T16:37:54.193Z",
            "procedure": "61e918809033533000bc1034",
            "user": "619664488f8190280002cde9",
            "version": 44,
            "deleted": false,
            "forms":
            [
                {
                    "active": true,
                    "oldorder": 1,
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "rows": [
                                {
                                    "order": 1,
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "required": true,
                                            "guid": "36559be6-a141-4723-834b-b8194d3108d9",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "input",
                                            "icon": "fa-pencil-alt",
                                            "rules": "required",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": ".....",
                                            "label": "SP"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "advanced": false,
                                            "required": true,
                                            "guid": "5e1b925c-b517-4fa1-8ba9-5af68ce2cc86",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "date",
                                            "icon": "fa-calendar",
                                            "rules": "required",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "Compilation data",
                                            "label": "DATA"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "guid": "7fa2a65b-f13a-4ea4-8371-0c5c5f96f8af"
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 2,
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "required": true,
                                            "dataSource": {
                                                "codelist": "60f6b7bd94457b1101e03435"
                                            },
                                            "guid": "9aedcaa0-0ac2-4339-b287-2e826766d14c",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "radio",
                                            "icon": "fa-dot-circle",
                                            "rules": "required",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "CUSTOMER AVAILABLE"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "required": true,
                                            "guid": "2d06c750-053b-4cdf-8684-f03754cda1c4",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "input",
                                            "icon": "fa-pencil-alt",
                                            "rules": "required",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "CUSTOMER REFERENCE"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "guid": "eb83691e-5652-48b1-8b0b-247f460e779a"
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 3,
                                    "fields": [],
                                    "guid": "dd80d230-b520-48eb-b4a4-5fe7d54f079f"
                                }
                            ],
                            "properties": [],
                            "dependencies": [],
                            "label": "SPEAKER",
                            "guid": "9d03344a-72c2-4d10-8a34-c63ac9935876"
                        },
                        {
                            "rows": [
                                {
                                    "order": 1,
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "dataSource": {
                                                "codelist": "61e91cd39033533000bc1038"
                                            },
                                            "required": true,
                                            "advanced": false,
                                            "guid": "545d42e5-7c38-435a-9753-a0859cb82a82",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "radio",
                                            "icon": "fa-dot-circle",
                                            "rules": "required|required",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "TYPE PORTANTE"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "guid": "ecbefe7e-3570-4e8b-8cb2-cc71eeed7379"
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 2,
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "required": false,
                                            "dataSource": {
                                                "codelist": "61e91dc69033533000bc103d"
                                            },
                                            "guid": "80ccaa3d-2a3a-44ed-8a09-fa32d38ce375",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "radio",
                                            "icon": "fa-dot-circle",
                                            "rules": "",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "CABLES"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "guid": "655ab2ba-b3d4-485d-b269-95c30062151c"
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 3,
                                    "guid": "5424ba1f-1f81-42ee-8ad5-32d678643e6f",
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "required": false,
                                            "dataSource": {
                                                "codelist": "61e91dc69033533000bc103d"
                                            },
                                            "guid": "6fe8882c-90d3-4438-a7b2-4ddb01ae4177",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "radio",
                                            "icon": "fa-dot-circle",
                                            "rules": "",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "CABLE"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 4,
                                    "guid": "772a8868-ea62-461c-bbd0-1054cd09fd68",
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "required": false,
                                            "dataSource": {
                                                "codelist": "61e91dd39033533000bc103e"
                                            },
                                            "guid": "74c01620-7420-4e5d-ae3a-ed91bbb5fc6c",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "radio",
                                            "icon": "fa-dot-circle",
                                            "rules": "",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "TERMINATE"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 5,
                                    "guid": "457b5246-458b-483d-830a-e22ee15b9556",
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "required": false,
                                            "dataSource": {
                                                "codelist": "61e91ddd9033533000bc103f"
                                            },
                                            "guid": "1673f32f-3c42-4700-8597-230299a0535d",
                                            "dndtype": "\"item\"",
                                            "type": "radio",
                                            "icon": "fa-dot-circle",
                                            "rules": "",
                                            "dependencies": [],
                                            "hint": "",
                                            "help": "",
                                            "label": "INFRASTRUCTURE"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "order": 6,
                                    "fields": [],
                                    "guid": "3c00be79-c504-4ec5-84af-b5ed8a2a7936"
                                }
                            ],
                            "properties": [],
                            "dependencies": [],
                            "label": "NETWORK STATUS",
                            "guid": "7d2de01c-6bbe-4c44-94bb-a884ebcf2d75"
                        },
                        {
                            "rows": [
                  {
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
            "published": false,
            "__v": 0
        }
        },
        "hash": "67a18a162d3ddb928be1e4c859ef88c8",
        "name": "FREE ACCESS - V.1 - 31.01.2022",
        "location": "null",
        "status": "closed",
        "utcOffset": 120,
        "user": {
            "_id": "619664488f8190280002cde9",
            "firstName": "Asd",
            "lastName": "Asd",
            "email": "asd@asd.it",
            "showInScheduler": false,
            "disableKeycloakLogin": false,
            "groups": [],
            "active": true,
            "allowADLogin": true
        },
        "deleted": false,
        "extendedTitle": [],
        "timeTracking": [],
        "workStart": "2022-01-31T16:37:58.948Z",
        "feSyncDate": "2022-04-01T15:06:30.204Z",
        "feVersion": "v3.7.1-20-g7d1a81035",
        "reopen": false,
        "originTime": "2022-01-31T16:38:28.573Z",
        "content": [
            {
                "field": "5E1B925C-B517-4FA1-8BA9-5AF68CE2CC86",
                "value": "2021-11-23T15:37:59.386Z"
            },
            {
                "field": "4F8412AB-5416-4C6C-9FBE-4ED5E6F08EE4",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "field": "96039A4B-D5D9-4EBD-9F01-FAD5124F2008",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "field": "36559BE6-A141-4723-834B-B8194D3108D9",
                "value": "14042547"
            },
            {
                "field": "9AEDCAA0-0AC2-4339-B287-2E826766D14C",
                "value": {
                    "Label": "Yes",
                    "Value": "Yes"
                }
            },
            {
                "field": "2D06C750-053B-4CDF-8684-F03754CDA1C4",
                "value": "Mr. John DOE"
            },
            {
                "field": "545D42E5-7C38-435A-9753-A0859CB82A82",
                "value": {
                    "Label": "Rame",
                    "Value": "Rame"
                }
            },
            {
                "field": "80CCAA3D-2A3A-44ED-8A09-FA32D38CE375",
                "value": {
                    "Label": "AT WALL",
                    "Value": "AT WALL"
                }
            },
            {
                "field": "74C01620-7420-4E5D-AE3A-ED91BBB5FC6C",
                "value": {
                    "Label": "AT WALL",
                    "Value": "AT WALL"
                }
            }
        ],
        "__v": 1,
        "closedBy": "61405b68db0e4c2900642020",
        "edited": {
            "at": "2022-04-01T15:06:30.204Z",
            "by": "NAME_SURNAME"
        },
        "documents": [
            {
                "_id": "61e960909033533000bc1105",
                "label": "ACCESS v.1",
                "description": ""
            }
        ],
        "tasks": [],
        "hasTasks": false
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to change the value of the "field" key with the value of the "label" key of its correspondent located within the complex structure (cases.version.forms.sections.rows.fields).

To make it possible to change this value, the value of the "field" key must coincide with the value of the "guid" key.

The final result should be:

```
{
      ....
                "field": "SP",
                "value": "14042547"
      ....
}
```

I tried to search about it but I couldn't find anything useful.

```
var caseInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(apiResponse);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse((string)caseInfo.ToString());
var fields = jObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
               .Where(prop => prop.Name.Contains("field") && prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.String).ToList();
```

First I deserialize the response. After that I create a JObject and I take a list of Field. But after doing this I don't know how to move forward.

Again thanks to everyone in advance and I hope I was clear :)

Comment: please confirm your JSON file - it broken.
also, check this url how to find token https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72062027/pick-only-one-record-from-a-json-array-in-c-sharp/72071796?noredirect=1#comment127356017_72071796

Comment: also, deserialize to class object, change value and serialize back to json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm), one can do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// Read the JSON file. 
var json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("input.json"));

// Extract label by GUID. Note that GUID case is inconsistent within the file, so we force upper case.
var labelByGuid = json.SelectTokens("cases.procedure.version.forms[*].sections[*].rows[*].fields[?(@.guid && @.label)]")
                      .ToDictionary(t => t["guid"]!.ToString().ToUpperInvariant(),
                                    t => t["label"]!.ToString());

// Update entries.
foreach (var entry in json.SelectTokens("cases.content[?(@.field)]"))
{
    var field = entry["field"]!.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
    if (!labelByGuid.TryGetValue(field, out var label))
        continue;
    
    entry["field"] = label;
}

// Write back the JSON object.
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
await using var outputStream = File.CreateText(@"output.json");
serializer.Serialize(outputStream, json);
```

Working demo available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_72231442).